# Can't provision scala/sbt from same file as jenkins service

Tags: linux, scala, jenkins, vagrant, puppet

I am fairly new to Puppet, so forgive me if this is a stupid question. I can't find any similar problems.

Here is what I am trying to do:
I am provisioning a jenkins environment using vagrant and puppet using the [jenkins-puppet](https://github.com/jenkinsci/puppet-jenkins/) module.
So far so good. I can create a master, and using the swarm plugin I can easily create a slave using the `jenkins::slave` package from the module using

```
class { 'jenkins::slave':
    masterurl => 'http://jenkins-master-url:8080',
    version => "2.0",
    slave_mode => "exclusive",
    labels => "scala sbt"
}
```

However I need scala and sbt on this slave, and that is where I run into problems. Installing works fine using

```
package { "openjdk": name => "openjdk-7-jre" }
## SBT
wget::fetch { "download sbt":
    source => "https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-0.13.2.deb",
    destination => "/tmp/sbt-0.13.2.deb",
    cache_dir => "/vagrant/cache/"
}
package { "sbt":
    provider => "dpkg",
    source => "/tmp/sbt-0.13.2.deb",
    require => [ File["/tmp/sbt-0.13.2.deb"], Package["scala"] ]
}

file_line { "sbt options":
    path => "/etc/environment",
    line => "SBT_OPTS=\"-Xms40M -Xmx2G -Xss2M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=1G -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=********\"",
    match => "^SBT_OPTS"
}

## SCALA
wget::fetch { "download scala":
    source => "http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/scala-2.10.3.deb",
    destination => "/tmp/scala-2.10.3.deb",
    cache_dir => "/vagrant/cache/"
}

package { "libjansi-java": }
package { "scala":
    provider => "dpkg",
    source => "/tmp/scala-2.10.3.deb",
    require => [ File["/tmp/scala-2.10.3.deb"], Package["openjdk"], Package["libjansi-java"] ]
}'
```

But when I try to run these commands from one puppet script it fails telling me a java6 dependency is missing (already installed with the jenkins service) and telling me to run `apt-get -f install`. When I ssh to the machine and do that it succeeds.

```
Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/dpkg --force-confold -i /tmp/scala-2.10.3.deb' returned 1: Selecting previously unselected package scala. ==> jenkins-slave: (Reading database ... 40786 files and directories currently installed.)
==> jenkins-slave: Preparing to unpack /tmp/scala-2.10.3.deb ...
==> jenkins-slave: Unpacking scala (2.10.3-400) ...
==> jenkins-slave: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of scala:
==> jenkins-slave:  scala depends on openjdk-6-jre | java6-runtime; however:
==> jenkins-slave:   Package openjdk-6-jre is not installed.
==> jenkins-slave:   Package java6-runtime is not installed.
==> jenkins-slave:
==> jenkins-slave: dpkg: error processing package scala (--install):
==> jenkins-slave:  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
==> jenkins-slave: Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
==> jenkins-slave: Errors were encountered while processing:
==> jenkins-slave:  scala
==> jenkins-slave: Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[jenkins-slave]/Package[scala]/ensure: change from purged to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/dpkg --force-confold -i /tmp/scala-2.10.3.deb' returned 1: Selecting previously unselected package scala.
==> jenkins-slave: (Reading database ... 40786 files and directories currently installed.)
==> jenkins-slave: Preparing to unpack /tmp/scala-2.10.3.deb ...
==> jenkins-slave: Unpacking scala (2.10.3-400) ...
==> jenkins-slave: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of scala:
==> jenkins-slave:  scala depends on openjdk-6-jre | java6-runtime; however:
==> jenkins-slave:   Package openjdk-6-jre is not installed.
==> jenkins-slave:   Package java6-runtime is not installed.
==> jenkins-slave:
==> jenkins-slave: dpkg: error processing package scala (--install):
==> jenkins-slave:  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
==> jenkins-slave: Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
==> jenkins-slave: Errors were encountered while processing:
==> jenkins-slave:  scala
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Package[sbt]: Dependency Package[scala] has failures: true
==> jenkins-slave: Warning: /Package[sbt]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> jenkins-slave: Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install openjdk-7-jdk' returned 100: Reading package lists...
==> jenkins-slave: Building dependency tree...
==> jenkins-slave: Reading state information...
==> jenkins-slave: You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
==> jenkins-slave: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
==> jenkins-slave:  openjdk-7-jdk : Depends: openjdk-7-jre (= 7u91-2.6.3-1~deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
==> jenkins-slave:                  Recommends: libxt-dev but it is not going to be installed
==> jenkins-slave:  scala : Depends: openjdk-6-jre but it is not installable or
==> jenkins-slave:                   java6-runtime
==> jenkins-slave: E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
==> jenkins-slave: Error: /Stage[main]/Java/Package[java]/ensure: change from purged to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install openjdk-7-jdk' returned 100: Reading package lists...
==> jenkins-slave: Building dependency tree...
==> jenkins-slave: Reading state information...
==> jenkins-slave: You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
==> jenkins-slave: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
==> jenkins-slave:  openjdk-7-jdk : Depends: openjdk-7-jre (= 7u91-2.6.3-1~deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
==> jenkins-slave:                  Recommends: libxt-dev but it is not going to be installed
==> jenkins-slave:  scala : Depends: openjdk-6-jre but it is not installable or
==> jenkins-slave:                   java6-runtime
==> jenkins-slave: E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Java::Config/Exec[update-java-alternatives]: Dependency Package[java] has failures: true
==> jenkins-slave: Warning: /Stage[main]/Java::Config/Exec[update-java-alternatives]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Java/Anchor[java::end]: Dependency Package[java] has failures: true
==> jenkins-slave: Warning: /Stage[main]/Java/Anchor[java::end]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Jenkins::Slave/User[jenkins-slave_user]/ensure: created
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Jenkins::Slave/Exec[get_swarm_client]/returns: executed successfully
==> jenkins-slave: Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install daemon' returned 100: Reading package lists...
==> jenkins-slave: Building dependency tree...
==> jenkins-slave: Reading state information...
==> jenkins-slave: You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
==> jenkins-slave: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
==> jenkins-slave:  scala : Depends: openjdk-6-jre but it is not installable or
==> jenkins-slave:                   java6-runtime
==> jenkins-slave: E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
==> jenkins-slave: Error: /Stage[main]/Jenkins::Slave/Package[daemon]/ensure: change from purged to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install daemon' returned 100: Reading package lists...
==> jenkins-slave: Building dependency tree...
==> jenkins-slave: Reading state information...
==> jenkins-slave: You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
==> jenkins-slave: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
==> jenkins-slave:  scala : Depends: openjdk-6-jre but it is not installable or
==> jenkins-slave:                   java6-runtime
==> jenkins-slave: E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

but when I use 2 scripts (first install the service, and the do the scala/sbt stuff, without running `apt-get -f install`) it succeeds.

Output from two files

```
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: Compiled catalog for jenkins-slave.jade.box in environment production in 1.97 seconds
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Jenkins::Slave/File[/etc/default/jenkins-slave]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}fc9a0abb2cdd083b052e2a1ae747fc13' ==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Java/Package[java-common]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Jenkins::Slave/File[/etc/init.d/jenkins-slave]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}dd82f282fd273568cdc22b7475a0ef0b'
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Java/Package[java]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Jenkins::Slave/User[jenkins-slave_user]/ensure: created
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Jenkins::Slave/Exec[get_swarm_client]/returns: executed successfully
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Timezone/File[/etc/timezone]/content: content changed '{md5}a1aea69cebd51fc6bebc02f7a550fbcf' to '{md5}6322bc8cb3ec53f5eea33201b434b74b'
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Timezone/Exec[update_timezone]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 events
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Timezone/File[/etc/localtime]/ensure: ensure changed 'file' to 'link'
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Jenkins::Slave/Package[daemon]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Jenkins::Slave/Service[jenkins-slave]/ensure: ensure changed 'stopped' to 'running'
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: Finished catalog run in 46.95 seconds
==> jenkins-slave: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> jenkins-slave: Running Puppet with sbt-scala.pp...
==> jenkins-slave: stdin: isseconds not a tty
==> jenkins-slave: Warning: Config file /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml not found, using Hiera defaults
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: Compiled catalog for jenkins-slave.jade.box in environment production in 1.22 seconds
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[jenkins-slave]/File_line[sbt options]/ensure: created
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[jenkins-slave]/Wget::Fetch[download sbt]/Exec[wget-download sbt]/returns: executed successfully
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[jenkins-slave]/Wget::Fetch[download sbt]/File[/tmp/sbt-0.13.2.deb]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}daa304595c0132c34b170b1e1a6b4044'
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[jenkins-slave]/Wget::Fetch[download scala]/Exec[wget-download scala]/returns: executed successfully
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[jenkins-slave]/Wget::Fetch[download scala]/File[/tmp/scala-2.10.3.deb]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}59f6ff95433df2105ed27dd77bb29a9e'
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[jenkins-slave]/Package[libjansi-java]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[jenkins-slave]/Package[scala]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[jenkins-slave]/Package[sbt]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
==> jenkins-slave: Notice: Finished catalog run in 3.65
```

So basically my question is, what does this error mean, and is it in some way possible to run it from one script? I would like that for the maintainability and keeping the code clean.

My vagrantfile for the two scripts looks like

```
config.vm.define "linux-slave" do |node|
    node.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"
    node.vm.hostname = "jenkins-slave.box"
    node.vm.network :private_network, ip: "172.28.128.12"

    node.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
        v.memory = 2048
        v.cpus = 2
    end

    node.vm.provision :shell, inline: "apt-get update && apt-get install -y puppet vim"
    node.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
        puppet.manifests_path = "jenkins-slave"
        puppet.module_path = ".modules"
        puppet.manifest_file = "default.pp"
        puppet.options = "--parser future"
    end

    node.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
        puppet.manifests_path = "jenkins-slave"
        puppet.module_path = ".modules"
        puppet.manifest_file = "sbt-scala.pp"
        puppet.options = "--parser future"
    end

end
```

And I want to get rid of the second `node.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet| ... end` part.

Is it the order in which puppet runs the commands? And can I force this in a way?

Any puppet guru's around that do understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The install is telling you you would need to install Java to install scala as [there is a dependency on 1.6 or later](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/#Software_Requirements)

There are many different ways to install Java but I would recommend to use a [puppet module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/java)

Comment: Java is already installed, that's the beauty of it
I use `package { "openjdk": name => "openjdk-7-jre" }` for thatm will update post

Comment: can you add `libxt-dev` package in your vagrantfile when doing `apt-get install -y puppet vim libxt-dev`

Comment: it turned out I did not have the dependencies right. Fixing them does install scala and sbt, however gives the following error
 `Error: Could not start Service[jenkins-slave]: Execution of '/usr/sbin/service jenkins-slave start' returned 6: Failed to start jenkins-slave.service: Unit jenkins-slave.service failed to load: No such file or directory.`

Comment: so the libxt-dev lib was the correct missing one ? as for the jenkins issue I am not sure, it says `jenkins-slave.service` is the file there ?

Comment: No, I did install java, but forgot scala to require it. That did fix installing scala and sbt.
The jenkins-slave.service file is not there `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`. But when I run it seperately it is and it is started. So my guess is that somewhere down the line it is not generating this file (there is a `etc/init.d/jenkins-slave`. But this is probably the implementation of [puppet jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/puppet-jenkins/blob/master/manifests/slave.pp). Thanks for your quick responses. I will investigate further and provide feedback

Comment: I think you should close this question as the scala provisionning part is now solved and open a specific one for the jenkins service

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the requirements were incorrect, JDK was required here.

```
package { "scala":
    provider => "dpkg",
    source => "/tmp/scala-2.10.3.deb",
    require => [ File["/tmp/scala-2.10.3.deb"], Package["openjdk"],    Package["libjansi-java"] ]
}'
```

Finally the problem was fixed requiring the file (as mentioned by @Frédéric)

```
exec { "enable-jenkins-slave":
    command => "/bin/systemctl enable jenkins-slave",
    require => File['/etc/init.d/jenkins-slave'],
    before => Service["jenkins-slave"],
}
```